# How to remove smell from a pluggable DAL

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am working with an application that is composed of several different, disconnected, components and each piece has a dependency on up to three different Data Stores (SQL Server, Doc Storage, BLOB Storage).

The SQL Server connection details are always known at design / deployment time, however the Doc and BLOB storage (both currently in Azure) details are sometimes provided at design time and sometimes provided at run time depending on the specific component I am working with.  Since there is consistent cost in using Azure my requirement is to build a pluggable data access layer that, in the event that the organization wanted to move away from Azure, there would be minimal effort in implementing a new data provider.  While the solution that I have come up fulfills the requirement, there are some code smells that I am looking to remove, but I am unsure on how I would achieve them (in the cleanest manner possible).  Below is a brief explanation of the structure that I have.

**Data Mappers**

```
public interface IBaseProvider
{
    void Configure(IDictionary<string, object> configValues);
}

public interface ISqlProvider : IBaseProvider
{
    ///CRUD omitted for clarity
}

public interface IBlobProvider : IBaseProvider
{
    ///CRUD omitted for clarity
}

public interface IDocProvider : IBaseProvider
{
    ///CRUD omitted for clarity
}

public class SqlDataProvider : ISqlProvider
{
     public void Configure(IDictionary<string, object> configValues)
     {
           //Do stuff
     }
}

public class DocDataProvider : IDocProvider
{
     public void Configure(IDictionary<string, object> configValues)
     {
           //Do stuff
     }
}

public class BlobDataProvider : IBlobProvider
{
     public void Configure(IDictionary<string, object> configValues)
     {
           //Do stuff
     }
}
```

The smell here is obviously `Configure(IDictionary<string, object> configValues)` and the reason for it is because:

- My implementation reaches into the configuration system to determine the type that I should be using
- In the event that I was providing connection details at runtime, I needed a way to pass those details into the provider class while pulling its type from the configuration system.

To actually provide instances of these objects to the applications, I wrote a Service Locator as such

**Service Locator**

```
public interface IProviderLocator
{
    T CreateInstance<T>(IDictionary<string, object> configValues) where T : IBaseProvider;

}

public sealed class ProviderLocator : IProviderLocator
{
     protected IDictionary<string, object> configValues;
     public T CreateInstance<T>(IDictionary<string, object> configurationValues) where T : IBaseProvider
    {
        configValues = configurationValues;
        return Initialize<T>();
    }

    private T Initialize<T>() where T : IBaseProvider
    {
        //reach into the configuration system to get providerType
        var provider = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(providerType);
        provider.Configure(configValues);

        return provider;
    }
}
```

The non-DI way to then get a concrete provider could then be something like

```
var database = new ProviderLocator().CreateInstance<ISqlProvider>(null);
```

The Service Locator implements both the locator pattern and provider "pattern" (someone check to see that Mark Seemann hasn't had a stroke ;] ), but despite the compelling arguments that Mark makes against these patterns [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/04/27/Providerisnotapattern/) and [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) I am not sure how to come off of this implementation.

The quick answer here is to probably use an Abstract Factory and to remove the dependency on the configuration system.

**Abstract Factory**

```
public interface IProviderFactory<T>
{
    T CreateInstance<T>(IDictionary<string, object> configValues)
}

public sealed class SqlProviderFactory : IProviderFactory<ISqlProvider>
{
     public T CreateInstance<T>(IDictionary<string, object> configurationValues)
    {
         return new SqlDataProvider(configurationValues);
    }
}
```

My two biggest concerns against implementing this pattern are:

- My classes will now have up 3 factory dependencies (one for each data provider);  this isn't a huge concern since my DI container will build my object graph but it does add a certain amount of clutter to the class.
- The Abstract Factory violates SOLID if and when I have to change the concrete provider (e.g. SqlDataProvider becomes AzureDataProvider)

**TL;DR / Overall Question**

My question is: does a pattern exist (or can one of the ones above be modified) that allows me the flexibility I am looking for that isn't as smelly while still being DI friendly?

Comment: I think http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is better suited place for this question.

Comment: Hey, thanks!  I didn't know that existed.